# AJAX question (web scraping) - advice needed :)

Tags: python, ajax, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scape this website -> https://www.techinasia.com/companies

when looking at the XHR calls that this site is making, it's clear that the site is pulling the results through an AJAX call, from this API :

> https://219wx3mpv4-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=219WX3MPV4&x-algolia-api-key=b528008a75dc1c4402bfe0d8db8b3f8e

However, when I visit this URL - all I see is:

```
{"message":"indexName is not valid","status":400}
```

I'm fairly certain that it has something to do with the Request Headers, Query String Parameters and Form Data -> [As seen in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK67a.jpg)

I'm just ensure on how to use this data in my code.

I've tried the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def create_dictionary():
    url = r"https://219wx3mpv4-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0%3BJS%20Helper%202.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=219WX3MPV4&x-algolia-api-key=b528008a75dc1c4402bfe0d8db8b3f8e"
    session = requests.Session()
    session.get("https://www.techinasia.com/companies")

    headers = {
        "Content-Type"      :   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept"            :   "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding"   :   "gzip, deflate, br",
        "User-Agent"        :   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"}

    response = session.post(url, headers=headers).json() 
    return(response)
```

But this function only returns the following:

```
{'message': 'No content in POST request', 'status': 400}
```

Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the headers. You can send as a string

```
import requests

data = '{"requests":[{"indexName":"companies","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=1000&page=0&facets=%5B%22*%22%2C%22entity_locations.country_name%22%2C%22entity_industries.vertical_name%22%2C%22funding_stages.stage_name%22%2C%22employee_count%22%2C%22job_posting_count%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}'
r= requests.post('https://219wx3mpv4-2.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.30.0;JS Helper 2.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=219WX3MPV4&x-algolia-api-key=b528008a75dc1c4402bfe0d8db8b3f8e',data=data)
print(r.json())
```